# Cipher.getInstance("DES") return different result on sun jre and ibm jre

Tags: java

I use Cipher.getInstance("DES") to encry and decrypt a message,and I find it get different result on sun jre and ibm jre.So I can't encry a mesage on AIX and then decrypt on Linux .I try to import sunjce and to use it on ibm jre environment and get the same result as use ibmjce,but it different from on sun jre.Is there a way to encry a message get the same result on sun jre and ibm jre ?
below code run on sun jre and ibm jre will get different result 。

```
    public static void test2() throws Exception {

    Security.addProvider(new SunJCE());
    Security.addProvider(new IBMJCE());
    String strKey = "12345678";
    KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES", "SunJCE");
    // KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES", "IBMJCE");
    System.out.println("KeyGenerator provider:" + generator.getProvider());
    //
    SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    secureRandom.setSeed(strKey.getBytes());
    generator.init(secureRandom);
    Key key = generator.generateKey();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES", "SunJCE");
    // Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES", "IBMJCE");
    System.out.println("Cipher provider:" + cipher.getProvider());
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    String strTest = "TESTtest123";
    byte[] byteTest = strTest.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] byteEncry = cipher.doFinal(byteTest);
    System.out.println("strTest:" + strTest);
    System.out.println("encode:" + new BASE64Encoder().encode(byteEncry));


}
```

Any idea, suggestion or workaround is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:
My appliction is deployed on windows , red hat linux and aix.They can pass an encryed mesage to each other,and the receiver will decrypt the message.It is work fine on win and linux.But the aix always get an Exception "javax.crypto.BadPaddingException:Given final block not properly padded" when try to decrypt the message from other system.the same thing happened when the window or linux try to decrypt the message from aix.Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Just because the ciphertext is different does not necessarily mean you can't decrypt it on the other platform. Did you actually try it? Did you make sure the key that gets used is the same?

Comment: Just use the default provider on both platforms. Don't try to second-guess them.

Comment: My appliction is deployed on windows , red hat linux and aix.They can pass an encryed mesage to each other,and the receiver will decrypt the message.It is work fine on win and linux.The aix always get an Exception "javax.crypto.BadPaddingException:Given final block not properly padded" when try to decrypt the message from other system.the same thing happened when the window or linux try to decrypt the message from aix.In my real code , I use getInstance("DES"),but it don't work.

Answer (score 1):

The entire purpose of a Service Provider Interface is that you specify the capability you need (DES), and the system provides an appropriate implementation for you. Don't try to select a specific provider, just use `getInstance("DES")` like you do for `SecureRandom`.

Note that you really do need to specify the complete cipher setup you want; just `DES` isn't specific enough, and this might be causing any incompatibilities you're seeing. `DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` is probably what you want, and if you're working on a new system, you should use AES instead.

Comment: I try use Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"), and the output is the same as Cipher.getInstance("DES")。I try to decrypt message on different jre,it still throw a exception " javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded"